# Javascript: Radio button and displaying images based on a vaule

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with displaying images based on the value chosen from a radio button. But I am currently running into a wall with making the code as short and efficient as possible. I have several categories to choose from and they way i am approaching the issue will require for me to write several `check_value#`. Is there a way to combine those two functions? so in the future if i have 5 or 7 categories i wont have to have a function for each. [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/)

```
<script>
 function check_value(val) {     
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox1");
    var img = imgs[val];
    if (val>0 && val<4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]
        el.src = "images/bike" + val + ".jpg";
        el.style.display = "";
    }    
}

 function check_value1(val) {    
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox2");
    var img = imgs[val];
    if (val>0 && val<4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]
        el.src = "images/tire" + val + ".jpg";
        el.style.display = "";
    }    
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Choose a bike</h2>
    <form name="builder">
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(0)'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
         <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(1)'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
         <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(2)'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
    </form>

<img id="imgBox1" src="#" style="display:none"> 

<h2>Choose a tire</h2>  
    <form name="tire">
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value1(0)'/> Michelin Pilot Road 3 Tires<br />
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value1(1)'/> Dunlop Roadsmart Sport-Touring Tires<br />
         <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value1(2)'/> Pirelli Scorpion Trail Tires<br />
    </form>

<img id="imgBox2" src="#" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, updated

make image name as bike#.jpg , tire#.jpg
bike0.jpg, bike1.jpg, bike2.jpg....

```
function check_value(val, id, type) {     
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox" + id);
    if (val>0 && val<4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]
       el.src = "images/"+ type + val + ".jpg";
       el.style.display = "";
  }
```

}

```
<h2>Choose a bike</h2>
<form name="builder">
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(0, 1, "bike")'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(1, 1, "bike")'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(2, 1, "bike")'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
</form>

<img id="imgBox1" src="#" style="display:none"> 

<h2>Choose a tire</h2>  
<form name="tire">
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(0, 2, "tire")'/> Michelin Pilot Road 3 Tires<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(1, 2, "tire")'/> Dunlop Roadsmart Sport-Touring Tires<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(2, 2, "tire")'/> Pirelli Scorpion Trail Tires<br />
</form>

<img id="imgBox2" src="#" style="display:none">
```

Comment: +1 Alright, I am currently trying this but I am not getting any image displayed. You can check the updated [LINK](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/)

Comment: in your code  var img = imgs[val]; 'imgs' is undefined, define this first

Comment: make image name as bike1.jpg, bike2.jpg bike#.jpg and fot tire tire#.jpg then remove this line : var img = imgs[val];

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EKaYP/) is a fiddle for you, using custom HTML attributes, and the [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) Javascript library:

Obviously you'd want to actually set the image's source, rather than displaying the url in a paragraph, but you get the idea, I'm sure.

```
// html
<input type="radio" name="tire" img-preview="tire-preview" img-loc="tire/1.jpg" /> First<br>
<input type="radio" name="tire" img-preview="tire-preview" img-loc="tire/2.jpg" /> Second<br>
<p id="tire-preview">
Load: -
</p>
<input type="radio" name="wheel" img-preview="wheel-preview" img-loc="wheel/1.jpg" /> Uno<br>
<input type="radio" name="wheel" img-preview="wheel-preview" img-loc="wheel/2.jpg" /> Dos<br>
<p id="wheel-preview">
Load: -
</p>​

// js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){

    var imageUri = "http://site.com/images/" + $(this).attr("img-loc");

    $("#" + $(this).attr("img-preview") ).text("Load: " + imageUri);

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<script>
function call(formNo,val)
  {if()//give your checkings here according to what you want
    {}
    alert(formNo+" "+val); //just for example what values you are getting
   }
</script>

<h2>Choose a bike</h2>
<form name="builder" id="1">
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1,0)'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(1,1)'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(1,2)'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
</form>
<img id="imgBox1" src="#" style="display:none"> 
<h2>Choose a tire</h2>  
<form name="tire" id="2">
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value1(2,0)'/> Michelin Pilot Road 3 Tires<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value1(2,1)'/> Dunlop Roadsmart Sport-Touring Tires<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value1(2,2)'/> Pirelli Scorpion Trail Tires<br />
</form>
<img id="imgBox2" src="#" style="display:none">
```